# smartctl Power_Cycle_Count on new SSD

Tags: ssd, smartctl

After one power cycle on my system and one smartctl long test, my Samsung EVO 1T SSD :

```
 ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE

...

 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       6

...
```

What is that `VALUE:099` about? Allowing for an automated QA cycle I'd expect that to be less that 10 certainly.  Is this a pre-owned disk? Or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threshold is 0, which indicates that this attribute counts down (typically from 100 or 99); it’s supposed to track wear, and the values given in the “value” and “worst” are indications of drive wear, not an absolute count of power cycles. As you can see from the raw value, your drive has had six power cycles so far.